# Insert google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation reduce iterating times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google map containsLocation method to search my marker inside of polygons.  I already have polygon data like

```
sogang_a.setMap(map);
yonsei_a.setMap(map);
yonsei_c.setMap(map); 
yonsei_e.setMap(map); 
ewha_yonsei_b.setMap(map); 
ewha_yonsei_d.setMap(map);
ewha_a.setMap(map);
```

And I'm rendering json data on my `/map/from_hasuk` and I call them by using

```
       $.get("/map/from_hasuk", function(data, status){
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        var infowindow = null;
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
        if ("<%= @univ %>"== "a") {
          if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, sogang_a) == true ){
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         position: latlng,
                         map: map
                     });
                marker.setMap(map); 
                }//if
              }//contain location 
           }//univ
         else if("<%= @univ %>"== "b") {

           if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= yonsei_a %>) == true || 
               google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= yonsei_c %>) == true ||
               google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= yonsei_e %>) == true ||
               google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= ewha_yonsei_b %>) == true ||
               google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= ewha_yonsei_d %>) == true ) {


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: latlng,
                 map: map
             });
          } //else if
      } //for loop
      } //get jquery
```

Oh, I'm using rails, and I have `@univ` parameter "a", and "b". The problem is, when I iterate the datas(I have 40 seeds) from `/map/from_hasuk` ,

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= ewha_yonsei_b %>) == true ||
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latlng, <%= ewha_yonsei_d %>) == true
```

reduces iterating times, which means when I put that conditions on my `else if`, counting time decreses. For example, I checked it by put `console.log("<%= @univ %>");` above my `if("<%= @univ %>" == "a") {`, and the outcome was

`putting that condition : 8, not putting: 40. erases one of them: 25`. Except that, everything works fine, not the problem of polygon, or phrases. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution from my long, boring trip. The problem is.. nothing! I mean just that code, `containsLocation` method works well. I got solution from my event and other DOM, which works with that gmap. If anybody looking for method related to `containLocation` for google map JS api, please use it. Thanks!